# ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

I'm working with mysql and I keep getting an error. I think it's because I don't have an alternate key, but I don't know how to set one.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Employee`.`Employee` (
          `PersonId` INT NOT NULL,
          `EmployeeID` INT NOT NULL,
          `FName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `MName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `LName` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
          `DOB` DATE NOT NULL,
          `Gender` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
          `Enthnicity` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `PersonalEmail` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
          `WorkEmail` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
          `Department` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
          `Building` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
          `OfficeNumber` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`PersonId`),
          UNIQUE INDEX `EmployeeID_UNIQUE` (`EmployeeID` ASC),
          UNIQUE INDEX `PersonalEmail_UNIQUE` (`PersonalEmail` ASC),
          UNIQUE INDEX `WorkEmail_UNIQUE` (`WorkEmail` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `Department`
            FOREIGN KEY ()
            REFERENCES `Employee`.`Department` ()
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first create table and after it make a foreign key!

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Employee`.`Employee` (
      `PersonId` INT NOT NULL,
      `EmployeeID` INT NOT NULL,
      `FName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `MName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `LName` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
      `DOB` DATE NOT NULL,
      `Gender` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
      `Enthnicity` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `PersonalEmail` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
      `WorkEmail` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
      `Department` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
      `Building` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
      `OfficeNumber` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`PersonId`),
      UNIQUE INDEX `EmployeeID_UNIQUE` (`EmployeeID` ASC),
      UNIQUE INDEX `PersonalEmail_UNIQUE` (`PersonalEmail` ASC),
      UNIQUE INDEX `WorkEmail_UNIQUE` (`WorkEmail` ASC)
      )
    ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Use Mysql workbench , or phpmyadmin for mysql modification to save time , and forget this problems!